# Formula or trick to tell when Excel data goes from increasing to decreasing

Tags: excel

I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I am working on a project that involves data increasing and then decreasing. I need to find when that shift happens. I usually just do this by scrolling through the data and visually finding it, but I wanted to know if there was a formula or trick to find it?
EX:

| DPS | Angle |
| --- | --- |
| 0.000 | 0.000 |
| ..... | ..... |
| 30.000 | 62.000 |
| ..... | ..... |
| 0.000 | 0.000 |

- The dataset is never the same amount(e.g. one excel file might have 1500 data points, and another might have 2300)
- Sometimes the data will increase/decrease for one or two cells(e.g. `0.0`,`0.5`,`0.3`,`0.3`,`0.5`,...)
- The data is always in decimals, never just whole numbers. (e.g. `62.300`,`61.287`,`61.198`)

Comment: do a subtract, if the result is negative then it is a decrease.

Comment: Find the max then find the last place the max is found, and that would be your pivot point?

Comment: Might there be multiple shifts in a data set that need to be detected? Also, you write `need to find when that shift happens`. What do you mean by ***when***? I do not see a column with timestamps so I assume you mean something else.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are looking for when consecutive members in a list change from descending to ascending, and the other way round?
If data in A1....A1000
In B2 put `=A2-A1` and drag down.
In C3 put `=IF(B3*B2<0,"changed","same")` and drag down.

Depending on what you are using this for, you may want to replace "same" with "_" so that the changes show more obviously.
Or replace "changed" with 1 and "same" with 0 so you can put a sum at the bottom to count how often it changes.
You could even have `=IF(B3*B2<0,IF(B3<0,-1,1),0)` which will put -1 when the direction changes from ascending to descending, and +1 when direction changes from descending to ascending.

If I have not understood your exact requirements accurately, this might still be enough of a pointer for you to modify to exactly what you do want?